# How to display them on same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display h4 and the paragraph on the same line, but it's not working. I tried to float them to the left, but nothing changed

```css
.offer {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.offer h4 {
  background-color: #f25c25;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Offer<br/> Expires<br/> Oct. 31,<br/> 2015!</h4>
  </div>
  <p class="paragraph">Know someone who’s fed up with soaring bank fees and declining customer service? Celebrate your credit union and its value. Each new member strengthens the credit union and lets us return earnings to you with better rates and higher dividends along
    with stellar services. Plus, when you refer a new member, you each get $20.*</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid, are you missing something from copy-pasting in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Fix your HTML and use `flex`:

```css
.offer {
display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0 5%;
}

.offer h4 {
  background-color: #f25c25;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
  margin-right:20px
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <h4>Offer<br/> Expires<br/> Oct. 31,<br/> 2015!</h4>
  <p class="paragraph">Know someone who’s fed up with soaring bank fees and declining customer service? Celebrate your credit union and its value. Each new member strengthens the credit union and lets us return earnings to you with better rates and higher dividends along
    with stellar services. Plus, when you refer a new member, you each get $20.*</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take care with flex if you are supporting legacy IE users, i.e <10

Comment: @JonP, indeed, use tables!

Answer (score 1):

Make both `.row` and `.paragraph` inline-blocks, apply width settings and `vertical-align: middle` to both:

```css
.offer {
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.offer h4 {
  background-color: #f25c25;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 200px;
}
.paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Offer<br/> Expires<br/> Oct. 31,<br/> 2015!</h4>
  </div>
  <p class="paragraph">Know someone who’s fed up with soaring bank fees and declining customer service? Celebrate your credit union and its value. Each new member strengthens the credit union and lets us return earnings to you with better rates and higher dividends along
    with stellar services. Plus, when you refer a new member, you each get $20.*</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just needed to move the `p` tag into the same `div`, and set the `p` tag to `display: table-cell`.

```css
.offer {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.offer h4 {
  background-color: #f25c25;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.offer p {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <h4>Offer<br/> Expires<br/> Oct. 31,<br/> 2015!</h4>
  <p class="paragraph">Know someone who’s fed up with soaring bank fees and declining customer service? Celebrate your credit union and its value. Each new member strengthens the credit union and lets us return earnings to you with better rates and higher dividends along with stellar services. Plus, when you refer a new member, you each get $20.*</p>
</div>
```